# ADLS to Azure Storage Sync Using AzCopy

Tags: azure-storage, azcopy, data-lake

Looking for some help to resolve the errors I'm facing. Let me explain the scenario. I'm trying to sync one of the ADLS Gen2 container to Azure BLOB Storage. I have `AzCopy 10.4.3`, I'm using `Azcopy Sync` to do this. I'm using the command below

`azcopy sync 'https://ADLSGen2.blob.core.windows.net/testsamplefiles/SAMPLE' 'https://AzureBlobStorage.blob.core.windows.net/testsamplefiles/SAMPLE' --recursive`

When I run this command I'm getting below error

```
REQUEST/RESPONSE (Try=1/71.0063ms, OpTime=110.9373ms) -- RESPONSE SUCCESSFULLY RECEIVED
   PUT https://AzureBlobStorage.blob.core.windows.net/testsamplefiles/SAMPLE/SampleFile.parquet?blockid=ZDQ0ODlkYzItN2N2QzOWJm&comp=block&timeout=901
   X-Ms-Request-Id: [378ca837-d01e-0031-4f48-34cfc2000000]

ERR: [P#0-T#0] COPYFAILED: https://ADLSGen2.blob.core.windows.net/testsamplefiles/SAMPLE/SampleFile.parquet: 404 : 404 The specified resource does not exist.. When Staging block from URL. X-Ms-Request-Id: [378ca837-d01e-0031-4f48-34cfc2000000]

   Dst: https://AzureBlobStorage.blob.core.windows.net/testsamplefiles/SAMPLE/SampleFile.parquet
REQUEST/RESPONSE (Try=1/22.9854ms, OpTime=22.9854ms) -- RESPONSE SUCCESSFULLY RECEIVED
   GET https://AzureBlobStorage.blob.core.windows.net/testsamplefiles/SAMPLE/SampleFile.parquet?blocklisttype=all&comp=blocklist&timeout=31
   X-Ms-Request-Id: [378ca84e-d01e-0031-6148-34cfc2000000]
```

So far I checked and ensured below things

- I logged into correct tenant while logging into `AzCopy`
- `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role was granted to my AD credentials

Not sure what else I'm missing as the file exists in the source and I'm getting the same error. I tried with SAS but I received different error though. I cannot proceed with SAS due to the vendor policy so I need to ensure this is working with oAuth. Any inputs is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the 404 error, you may check if there is any typo in the command and the path `/testsamplefiles/SAMPLE` exists on both source and destination account. Also, please note that from the [tips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs).

> Use single quotes in all command shells except for the Windows Command
>   Shell (cmd.exe). If you're using a Windows Command Shell (cmd.exe),
>   enclose path arguments with double quotes ("") instead of single
>   quotes ('').

From [azcopy sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-sync) supported scenario:

> Azure Blob <-> Azure Blob (Source must include a SAS or is publicly
>   accessible; either SAS or OAuth authentication can be used for
>   destination)

We must provide include a SAS token in the source, but I tried the below code with AD authentication.

```
azcopy sync "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/blob]?[SAS]" "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/blob]"
```

but got the same 400 error as [the Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/860).

Thus, in this case, after my validation, you could use this command to sync one of the ADLS Gen2 container to Azure BLOB Storage without executing `azcopy login`. If you have login in, you can run `azcopy logout`.

```
azcopy sync "https://nancydl.blob.core.windows.net/container1/sample?sv=xxx" "https://nancytestdiag244.blob.core.windows.net/container1/sample?sv=xxx" --recursive --s2s-preserve-access-tier=false
```

[image]